# Como fazer um INSERT no postgresql com valor default condicional?

Tags: postgresql, sql-insert, value, default

Temos a seguinte tabela simplificada para o exemplo:

```
create table teste(
        id serial not null
        );
```

Os comandos abaixo causam erro de sintaxe:

```
insert into teste(
        select (case when 1=1 then DEFAULT end)
        );
```

ou:

```
insert into teste(
        select coalesce(null::integer, DEFAULT)
        );
```

> ```
> ERROR:  syntax error at or near "DEFAULT"
> LINE 2:         select (case when 1=1 then DEFAULT end)
>                                            ^
> ********** Error **********
> ERROR: syntax error at or near "DEFAULT"
> SQL state: 42601
> ```

Provisoriamente uso o seguinte:

```
   insert into teste(
    select coalesce(null::integer, nextval('teste_id_seq'::regclass))
    );
```

O Objetivo é informar o valor DEFAULT do campo, seja ele serial ou não, de forma condicional sem informar a função ou o valor da constante definida na tabela, pois esse valor pode mudar futuramente e irá causar uma inconsistência nos comandos que chamam o INSERT. Isso é possível?

Comment: A palavra DEFAULT deve ser informada na parte de VALUES do INSERT e não na lista de campos.

Comment: @anonimo Obrigado, mas, observe que o DEFAULT de exemplo acima não está na declaração dos campos, o INSERT é feito somente com o valor, que é uma das formas de se fazer isso sem obrigatoriamente informar o nomes do campos, desde os valores que estejam na mesma ordem de tipos aceita pelo tipo do registro da tabela.

Comment: Não entendi. Não tem sentido você querer especificar o termo DEFAULT se na criação da tabela você não informou qual é o valor DEFAULT.

Comment: @anonimo:"__...na criação da tabela você não informou qual é o valor DEFAULT__". Implicitamente defini sim. Observe que a declaração da tabela fica assim: `...id integer **default** nextval('teste_id_seq'::')`

Answer (score 1):

O valor default do campo deve ser informado no momento da criação da tabela, conforme segue:

```
CREATE TABLE products (
    product_no integer DEFAULT nextval('products_product_no_seq'),
    price numeric DEFAULT 9.99,
    ...
);
```

Mais detalhes na [documentação do PostgreSQL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/ddl-default.html).

Comment: Obrigado, mas, isso não responde à pergunta. O valor DEFAULT também pode ser implicitamente informado usado a palavra reservada DEFAULT no comando INSERT.
[link] https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/sql-insert.html [link]

Comment: Por que precisa passar no INSERT? Porque o DEFAULT muda? Se muda não é mais fácil controlar na aplicação? Não pode ajustar o DEFAULT alterando o que foi definido no create table?

Comment: O Código completo é chamado de uma trigger num "UPSERT" (ON CONFLICT no postgresql). Como o id é incrementado sob certa condição, se não for encontrado a id para entregar ao "ON CONFLICT UPDATE" ele deve inserir o DEFAULT.

Comment: Então se não for encontrado o ID, move NULL que ele utilizará o default, conforme definido no CREATE.

Comment: Desculpa, não entendi o que quis dizer com "move NULL".

Comment: Passa NULL ou não passa o campo no insert!

Comment: Passar NULL não chama o Default, visto que o campo é chamado explicitamente. O banco retornará "ERROR:  null value in column "codigo" violates not-null constraint".
Não passar o campo não atende ao requisito de informar o código explicitamente sob certa condição, informado acima.

Comment: Da documentação: "To insert the next value of the sequence into the serial column, specify that the serial column should be assigned its default value. This can be done either by excluding the column from the list of columns in the INSERT statement, or through the use of the DEFAULT key word.". https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-SERIAL